# Complex Analysis. How to use cauchy intergral

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

Given the following integral of gamma on the path $[0,2]$ and $[-2,2]$ we have the integral $$ \int_\gamma \frac{z} {(z^2-1)(z-3)}dz$$

I set it up like

$$ \int_\gamma \frac{\frac{z}{(z+1)(z-3)}}{z-1}=2\pi i $$

and i get that =

$$ \frac{-\pi i}{2} $$

and then i did the following for $[-2,2]$ but i dont believe they are set up correctly and was wondering if i can have some guidance or the error pointed out

$$ \int_\gamma \frac{\frac{z}{(z^2-1)}}{z-3}=2\pi i $$

then after everything i get its = 0 or pi i/4

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please type your questions instead of posting images. Images can't be browsed and are not accessible to those using screen readers. If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I tried to fix it, but only worked for certain things

Comment: It's alright ! Let me fix it. The small misunderstanding there was that in order to write fractions, one uses : \frac{} {} :) not \frac{} {} {}. Please Look at my revision if it s not clear.

Comment: Good Luck with latex if you're begining with it, it is really useful, trust me

Comment: I have been using it! I just didn't know you could use it on here! Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your notation, by $[-2,2]$ you mean the circle of radius $2$ centered at $-2$.  But the integrand's only pole is then at $z=-1$.

So you get $\oint_Cf(z)/(z+1)$, where $f(z)=z/((z-1)(z-3))$. So the integral is equal to $2\pi if(-1)=2\pi i(-1/8)=-\pi i/4$.

Comment: Yes thats what i get and mean

Comment: I was wondering if this was correct though? I have seen different answers and i am doubting what i got